# Django - pass these specific model objects to one template

Tags: django, django-views

Model

```
class Person( models.Model ):
    first_name = models.CharField( max_length=50 )
    last_name = models.CharField( max_length=50 )    

    def __str__(self): 
        return "{0} {1}".format( self.first_name, self.last_name )
```

View Function

```
def getPersonData(request):
    currPersonData = {}    

    # get current user
    currentUser = request.user
    # create a person object based on who is logged in. 
    person = Person.objects.create(first_name=currentUser.first_name,
                                   last_name=currentUser.last_name) 

    # getting front loaded personMeta, that user CANNOT provide                              
    personDetails = PersonMeta.objects.filter(legal_first_name=currentUser.first_name,
                                              legal_last_name=currentUser.last_name).values()
    # setting hash key for dict 
    currUserKey = "{0} {1}".format(currentUser.first_name, currentUser.last_name)

    # setting dictionary
    # data[currUserKey] = currentUser
    # if person details is not false
    if (personDetails):
        currPersonData[currUserKey] = personDetails    

    return currPersonData
```

View Calling Function and returning data to template.

```
def signup(request):
    currPersonData = getPersonData( request )
    return render( request, '/signup.html/', {'data': sorted( currPersonData.items( ) )}, )
```

URL

```
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup),
```

Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SignUp</title>
</head>
<body>    

    {% for tuple in data %}
    <p>Tuple key: {{ tuple.0 }}</p>
    {% for key, value in tuple.1.0.items %}
        <p>Dict key, value: {{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}    


    {% for values in eb %}
        <p>values</p>
    {% endfor %}    

</body>
</html>
```

All of the above seems to be working the way I expect it to. I can get the data I am after and pass it to a template. Now I would like to take all objects of the below model, and pass all these objects it to my '/signup.html/' in addition to what is being passed above, so I can start form processing.

```
class Elective( models.Model ):
    elective_title = models.CharField( max_length=100 )
    elective_description = models.CharField( max_length=100 )    

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format( self.elective_title )
```

I tried following 
[Django Pass Multiple Models to one Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187751/django-pass-multiple-models-to-one-template)

and 
[Refer to multiple Models in View/Template in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419328/refer-to-multiple-models-in-view-template-in-django)

With unsuccessful results, and now that I have been working on this for some time now I thought my next best move is to ask for help.

Comment: Why not simply pass more variables in your context? (in the `render` function).

Comment: @Wtower would you mind pointing at an example or documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass multiple models in the context of your view. In your view function, for example:

```
def signup(request):
    currPersonData = getPersonData( request )
    return render( request, '/signup.html/', {
        'data': sorted( currPersonData.items( ) ),
        'electives': Elective.objects.all(),
    })
```

Comment: I will mark this as an accepted answer please note that I used    `  'electives': Elective.objects.all().values() `