# Having two Generic ListViews on the same page

Tags: python, django, listview

Currently can show objects list under Activities, but Interview remains empty (although there are bullet points corresponding to the number of Interview objects - just the text is not showing).

**views.py:**

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
  template_name = 'expcore/index.html'
  model = Activity
  context_object_name = 'activities_list'
  queryset = Activity.objects.all()

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['interviews_list'] = Interview.objects.all()
    return context
```

**index.html:**

```
  <div>
<h1>Activities</h1>
<ul>
{% for activity in activities_list %}
    <li><a href='/activity/{{ activity.name }}'></a></li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No activities available yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h1>Interviews</h1>
<ul>
{% for interview in interviews_list %}
    <li><a href='/interview/{{ interview }}'>{{ interview.name }}</a></li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No interviews available yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas why Interview objects aren't showing?

Comment: Maybe duplicate [Django Pass Multiple Models to one Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187751/django-pass-multiple-models-to-one-template) ?

Comment: @IsaBek Thank you for the reply. I'm completely new to Python/Django, and it's really hard for me to adapt other people's code to my own. Would it be possible for you to provide some example code?

Comment: That's really the best way to learn. If you just copy paste, you'll not be able to DEBUG your own code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override `get_context_data` function in the `IndexView`. And there you can send objects more than one.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
  template_name = 'expcore/index.html'
  model = Activity
  context_object_name = 'activities_list'
  queryset = Activity.objects.all()

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['interviews_list'] = Interview.objects.all()
    return context
```

On the template you can do like that.

For activity

```
{% for activity in activities_list %}
{% endfor %}
```

For interview

```
{% for interview in interviews_list %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The list for Activities is now showing, but there is still nothing under Interviews (even though there are bullet points under Interviews - just the names of the Interviews aren't showing). Do you have any ideas as to why this may be?

Comment: Could you show your IndexView and code which prints interviews?

Comment: Are you sure that you override `get_context_data`  function in `IndexView`? I mean `get_context_data` under the `IndexView`.