# How to Load multiple Model to single template in Django 2

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-2.1

How to load multiple models in one template in Django 2? 
i've read [Django Pass Multiple Models to one Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187751/django-pass-multiple-models-to-one-template) but, i'm lost in the answer and there is no specific answer there to get that view into the template,

Im trying to pass 3 models in views to template, which is Info, Slogan & Berita.

My `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Artikel, Berita, Data, Galeri, Info, Slogan, Profil
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

def home(request):
    extra_context : {"info" : Info.objects.all(),
                     "slogan": Slogan.objects.all(),
                     "berita": Berita.objects.all(),
                    #and so on for all the desired models...
                    }
    return render (request, 'blog/home.html')

class HomeListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'slogan'    
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    queryset = Info.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slogan'] = Slogan.objects.all()
        context['berita'] = Berita.objects.all()
        # And so on for more models
        return context
```

my template `home.html` looks like:

```
{% for slogans in slogan %}                                     
  <p>{{ slogans.konten }}</p>
  <p>{{ slogans.author }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

my url `urls.py` looks like:

```
from blog.views import HomeListView

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', HomeListView.as_view(), name="home"),
   ]
```

and page source on browser shows nothing.

Im stuck on this, i found at least 3 similar result on this site but not works for me.

Comment: Your `context_object_name` should be 'info' since it's a list of `Info` objects. This is conflicting with you setting the `context['slogan']`. Apart from that your `HomeListView` is correct. What do you mean by "page source shows nothing"? Empty? Not even an <html> tag?

Comment: the `<html>` tag between  `{% for slogans in slogan %}`  and `{% endfor %}` is empty